# Composition of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear maps say from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Am I right to say that the null space of $T_1$ is a subspace of the null space of the composite $T_2\circ T_1$ where $(T_2\circ T_1)(u)=T_2(T_1(u))$,$u\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you know the definition of the null space and the definition of $T_2\circ T_1$?

Comment: Is $T_2\circ T_1(x)=T_2(T_1(x))$ or the other way around? If it is like this then $T_2\circ T_1$ maps to $0$ any vector from the null space of $T_1$, and possibly more, so yes, it is a subspace.

Comment: Yes, you are.${}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_1:V\to W$ and $T_2:W\to U$ be linear maps. Then $$\ker T_1 = \{v\in V : T_1v=0\}\subset V,$$ whereas $$\ker T_2\circ T_1 = \{v\in V: T_2(T_1(v)) = 0\}\subset V.$$ Indeed, if $v\in\ker T_1$ then $T_2(T_1(v)) = T_20 = 0$ so that $v\in\ker T_2\circ T_1$ and hence $\ker T_1$ is a subspace of $\ker T_2\circ T_1$.

Comment: Since we do $T_1$ first for the composite $T_2\circ T_1$, so isn't it $ker T_2\circ T_1\subset V$ as well?

Comment: If $T_1,T_2: V\to V$ then $\ker T_2\circ T_1\subset V$, indeed.

Comment: Since you substitute $w$ into $T_1$ it has to be in $V$, not $W$, in all cases. $\ker T_1$ and  $\ker T_2\circ T_1$ are always in the same space ($V$), and the former is always a subspace of the latter.

Comment: @Conifold You are correct, I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are: for all linear maps $T_1:V\to W$ and $T_2:W\to H$, it is always the case that $\ker (T_2\circ T_1)\supseteq \ker T_1$. In fact, if $T_1(x)=0$, then $T_2(T_1(x))=T_2(0)=0$.